# How to trim between wood floor and circular opening for spiral stairs

Tags: flooring, stairs, trim

I recently replaced the carpet in my attic with a floating mdf backed engineered hardwood floor.  the attic has a circular opening in the floor for a spiral staircase.

[image]

The face of the opening is 3/8" plywood. My question is:  How do I trim the curved edge between the floor and the opening face?

[image]

I haven't been able to find a product designed for this purpose at the local hardware store or in a Google search.  Something made of wood would be ideal, but that seems impractical.  Probably something made of a  flexible material would be an easier option.  If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Your search didn't come up with product lines [like this](http://signatureflex.com/)? A combination of their stair nosing and T-molding would probably do well. Unfortunately you'd normally work out transitions _before_ laying the floor to allow the proper clearance. You might need to cut in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make a polygon (24 - 1/2x2 cut at 82.5 degrees + wood glue + a lap joint for strength) that can then be cut into a circle and maybe routed with a detail. You would see the grain changes in direction, but that wouldn't be a deal breaker to me. It would be a bit time consuming with all the cuts and glue up.

I've also seen videos of people using PVC trim and a clothes iron to bend long thin strips and it seems to work very well, but I've never tried it.

Comment: You may get the vertcal piece to bend just fine, and can probably even use a single strip of thin wood, but the horizonal section of trim wouldn't bend unless it's very thin.  This cut out method is what I was thinking.

Comment: it're fairly easy to convert a plunge router into a compass (flip the edge guide upside down and screw it to an arm)